# VBA Outlook: How to determine the last item of folder?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

How can I delete a search folder in Outlook using VBA?

I found the code here that deletes the search folder: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-an-outlook-search-folder-using-vba/

Because I'm still noob in VBA, I can't understand some parts of the code.

Is there another way to delete outlook search folder using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx).

You can use the [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863914.aspx) method of the Folder class.